# Calculating the total and average of marks using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am new into Javascript btw thus I really hope someone can help me point out my mistake. I have done all the things that the question asked except for the calculation for total and average part. I got it wrong and I dont know what went wrong. Example marks I have keyed in were 1,2,3,4. Supposed to be the total and average should be 10 and 2.5 but it displayed 1234 and 308.5. Here`s what I have tried :

```js
function findTotal() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("Mark1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("Mark2").value;
  var num3 = document.getElementById("Mark3").value;
  var num4 = document.getElementById("Mark4").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
}

function findAverage() { 
  var num1 = document.getElementById("Mark1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("Mark2").value;
  var num3 = document.getElementById("Mark3").value;
  var num4 = document.getElementById("Mark4").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark1" /><br>
  Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark2" /><br>
  Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark3" /><br>
  Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark4" /><br> <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="findTotal()" Value="Find Total" />
  <input type="button" onClick="findAverage()" Value="Find Average" />
</form><br>

Result : <br>
<span id = "result"></span>
```

Comment: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) should help... The `value` you have are stings.

Comment: `document.getElementById("Mark1").value` isn't a number, but a string. You first need to convert it to a number.

Comment: How can I convert from string to number? And which part should I fix? @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: In my comment, the blue underlined words are links to useful documentation.

Comment: You should probably place your JS in the <head> section of your code.

Comment: You should put all the js in a `<script>` tag, the code in `<pre><code>` will execute when it is inside script tag

Comment: The HTML and JS files are separated actually. But I did linked the HTML to the JS file. @Ayush

Comment: I thought we can place our JS anywhere in the code? @Toby

Comment: The fix should be this:         var num1 = parstInt(document.getElementById("Mark1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Mark2").value);
        var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Mark3").value);
        var num4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Mark4").value); -- You are very welcome!

Comment: @Anis Amira, sorry... I ment to say place the script code inside <script> tag.

Comment: And to find the total, the code is the same as what I did right? [ document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4; ] Because I`ve run it, but it didnt display anything @Toby

Comment: None of the answers take into account that parseInt or parseFloat could return NaN if the input/text input is not strictly numeric; type="number" should be used instead

Comment: @Dexygen, if(isNaN(num1) && isNaN(num2) && isNaN(num3) && isNaN(num4)){ console.log(error);}

Comment: @Toby I think if any single one isNaN it's an error, so maybe you should be using logical or `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value is string "1"+"2"+"3"+"4" = "1234"
so you need to convert it to number so you could just add `parseFloat();`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>MARK</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script src="mark.js"></script>
    <form>
    Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark1" /><br>
    Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark2" /><br>
    Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark3" /><br>
    Mark : <input type="text" id="Mark4" /><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onClick="findTotal()" Value="Find Total" />
    <input type="button" onClick="findAverage()" Value="Find Average" />
    </form>
    <br>
    Result : <br>
    <span id = "result"></span>
    
    </body>
    <script>
    

function findTotal()
{
        var num1 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark1").value);
        var num2 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark2").value);
        var num3 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark3").value);
        var num4 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark4").value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4);
}

function findAverage() 
{ 
        var num1 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark1").value);
        var num2 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark2").value);
        var num3 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark3").value);
        var num4 =parseFloat( document.getElementById("Mark4").value);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4;
}
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!